# Filling Null values with respective mean

Tags: python, pandas, kaggle

I have a dataset as follow -

```
alldata.loc[:,["Age","Pclass"]].head(10)
Out[24]: 
    Age  Pclass
0  22.0       3
1  38.0       1
2  26.0       3
3  35.0       1
4  35.0       3
5   NaN       3
6  54.0       1
7   2.0       3
8  27.0       3
9  14.0       2
```

Now I want to fill all the null values in `Age` with the mean of all the `Age` values for that respective `Pclass` type.

Example - 
In the above snippet for null value of `Age` for `Pclass = 3`, it takes mean of all the age belonging to `Pclass = 3`. Therefore replacing null value of `Age = 22.4`.

I tried some solutions using `groupby`, but it made changes only to a specific `Pclass` value and converted rest of the fields to null. How to achieve `0` null values in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

**1]** `transform` and lambda function

```
In [41]: df.groupby('Pclass')['Age'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
Out[41]:
0    22.0
1    38.0
2    26.0
3    35.0
4    35.0
5    22.4
6    54.0
7     2.0
8    27.0
9    14.0
Name: Age, dtype: float64
```

Or use

**2]** `fillna` over `mean`

```
In [46]: df['Age'].fillna(df.groupby('Pclass')['Age'].transform('mean'))
Out[46]:
0    22.0
1    38.0
2    26.0
3    35.0
4    35.0
5    22.4
6    54.0
7     2.0
8    27.0
9    14.0
Name: Age, dtype: float64
```

Or use

**3]** `loc` to replace `null` values

```
In [47]: df.loc[df['Age'].isnull(), 'Age'] = df.groupby('Pclass')['Age'].transform('mean')

In [48]: df
Out[48]:
    Age  Pclass
0  22.0       3
1  38.0       1
2  26.0       3
3  35.0       1
4  35.0       3
5  22.4       3
6  54.0       1
7   2.0       3
8  27.0       3
9  14.0       2
```